# Silverstrip 4 Show categories which have post

Tags: silverstripe-4

I have 6  categories as shown in the image . I have posts in finance and enterprise

categories . Ao i dont want to show the other categories in the drop down . and when i add a new post to other category suppose for aircraft then aircraft should also show in the drop down . how can i acheive that .

[image]

i have tried the following filter but it did not work

```
filter(array('ParentID' => $this->ID , 'EventDate:GreaterThan' => $curDate))
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
        // In this query I assume you got this structure -> [Category 'has_many/many_many' Posts]
        $categoriesWithImages = Category::get()->filter([
            'Posts.ID:GreaterThan' => 0,
            'Posts.EventDate:GreaterThan' => $curDate,
        ]);
```